# Scanner is never closed in method, but I think it does actually close every time the method ends?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, java.util.scanner

```
public static void maxintRecursive(int max) {

// create scanner
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// asks user for integer input
        int a = in.nextInt();



// checks if integer input satisfies exit condition, closes scanner, prints max and returns
        if (a <= 0) {
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Max int is: " + max);
            return;
        }

// checks if input is greater than previous max registered int
        if (a > max) {
            max = a;
        }
// calls itself again
        maxintRecursive(max);
    }
```

I can compile and run it successfully, but at line 3 it underlines "in" saying that it's never closed
However, this method keeps calling itself until you reach the exit condition (a <=0) under which the scanner does in fact get closed

Is it an error? Is it actually never getting closed and I'm getting a memory leak?

Should I pass a scanner in the method from the main, or would it be the same?

This recursive method asks the user for an integer input and returns the maximum integer received once the user inputs 0 or less

I created a scanner inside the method and closed it when the recursive method reaches its exit condition

I expected the scanner to be closed by my code inside the exit condition, but VS Code says it never gets closed

Comment: Not sure why you would do this with a recursive method, but if you must it would be better to create a single Scanner outside the method before calling it rather than creating a new Scanner each time the method is called. You would have multiple Scanners all reading from System.in with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time method its called, it creates its own local variables. For instance if you have method like

```
void foo(int n) { 
    int x = n + 1; 
    if (x < 2) 
        foo(x); 
}
```

and you call it like `foo(0);` then while executing it will have *its own* two *local variables* `n=0` (method parameter) and `x = n+1 = 0+1 = 1` (declared in body of method).
Then when you invoke recursively `foo(x);` which will end up as `foo(1)` that invocation will create another set of `n` `x` *local variables* which will be holding values `n=1` `x=2`.

Similarly in your case, each time you call `maxintRecursive` method it creates *its own* separate `Scanner in = new Scanner(...)` object. ***So if you called your method N times, the N `Scanner` objects ware created*** (all of them reading from `System.in`). Even if you call `in.close();` in method handling `if (a <= 0)` it will only close Scanner created by *that* recursive invocation. Other Scanners, created in previous method calls will never be closed.

Possible solution could be *also* adding `in.close();` at the end of your method (after recursive call), which will ensure that each method will close its own Scanner.

But ***preferred*** solution would be preventing creating so many Scanners in the first place. Instead create one in `main` method and *pass* it to recursive method as parameter. Since it will be *passed* Java will not force you to close that scanner in method itself, but in *scope* where it was created (the main method).

To do this you need to let `maxintRecursive` *accept* Scanner as parameter by modifying its declaration like

```
public static void maxintRecursive(int max, Scanner in) {
    //...
}
```

This way all you need now is something like

```
public static main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    maxintRecursive(-1, scanner);
    scanner.close();
}
```

---

BTW another reason we avoid creating Scanner which handles `System.in` inside our own methods is fact that closing such Scanner by that method would also close `System.in`. This means when you will try to call your method again it will create Scanner which will try to read from already close `System.in`. Again, preferred solution in such case is to *pass* Scanner handling System.in as method parameter.